# Custom Font Encoding

Tags: java, encoding, fonts, jasper-reports, arabic

I'm trying to represent Arabic fonts with Jasper report SO I follow a custom font extension method and adding one Arabic font as an extension "Andalus or Arial Unicode MS"

But when I try to

I got an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font : 
pdfFontName   : Helvetica
pdfEncoding   : Identity-H
isPdfEmbedded : true

Caused by: ExceptionConverter: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: Identity-H
```

MY JXML as below

```
<textElement>
    <font fontName="Andalus" size="12" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
</textElement>
```

Environment Setup

- Jasper Report 4.5
- Windows 7
- JDK jdk1.6.0_17

Could anyone help what's wrong with the font or recommend a specific jar?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using font name "Arial" which is defined before on Japser so the

1. The first step to name your font with another custom name like "myfont" 
   so that you make sure that your font is loaded to the classpath or not
2. Second step I follow the below post first method (Hard way ) and it work fine :)
   [That blog post](http://javaskeleton.blogspot.sg/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and its very annoying so to make it clear to all here how you do this

> first 
>   create font by follow this [ARABIC & UTF-8](http://qussay.com/2010/12/10/arabic-and-utf-8-languages-with-ireport/)

and then

on the field or label that may has Arabic content go to its properties by right click or on the properties pallet of it , and make these changes

Check the box PDF embed
Choose Identity-H (Unicode with horizontal writing) from PDF encoding
Choose the font Arial if not there add it to the jasper fonts folder in the installation directory and add it to the class path in settings
Rerun in PDF mode ... it will work